# Cannot find msi product code on 64-bit Windows

Tags: windows-installer, registry

Consider the following:

I use VS2010 to create a C# .NET 32-bit windows service (target=x86, framework=4.0) and a corresponding setup project (.msi).

My developement machine is a 32-bit Widnows XP Professional SP3.

I have a special need: I have to be able to programatically uninstall my service from a separate 32-bit application. For that pupose the uninstalling application has to know the product code of the installed service when uninstallation is to take place (in order to be able to call "msiexec.exe /uninstall ").

I have solved this by letting the 32-bit uninstall-application search through the registry for installed components until it comes across the one that matches my services' name, and then it fetches the corresponding product code. This is very simple and it works just fine.

Today i tried installing my service on 64-bit Windows 7. The service runs fine, but when it comes to uninstalling, my 32-bit uninstall-application can no longer find the product code in the registry. This is because the 32-bit uninstaller-application can only see the redirected (wow6432node) part of the registry while the installation information was (for unknown reasons) put in the original, undirected part.

How can I come about this problem?

- Can I force the installer to put the install-information in the redirected part of the registry?
- Can I get access to and scan the undirected registry part from my 32-bit uninstaller-application?
- Can I - during installation - somehow retrieve the product code and store it in an alternative place (accessable from my 32-bit uninstaller)?
- Is there another way of retrieving the product code that does not involve searching the registry?

Comment: Another idea: Should I create a small 64-bit application that does the registry searching for me and launch it from my 32-bit uninstaller-application?

Comment: Only 64-bit packages use the 64-bit registry hive. 32-bit packages write in Wow6432Node. Are you using a 64-bit installer?

Comment: I use the standard setup project from VS2010, and it targets x86 (according to the indicator in top line). I cannot understand too why it then writes to the 64-bit hive.

Comment: Select your setup project in Solution Explorer and check Target Platform in its Properties pane.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I checked it and it shows x86 as it should. I tried deleting all bin and obj folders from my solution and recompiled it from scratch, but with same result. Any more suggestions?

Comment: If it's x86, then your installer can create registry entries only in the Wow6432Node. Something else is creating the 64-bit entries.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then spelunking through the registry you should use WiX DTF's Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller assembly to make the Windows Installer API calls to determine the ProductCode you are looking for.